# Is there a difference between Firestore's customization collections in performance and costs?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

i am building chat app but i am struggling between two option related to users messages in chat

option 1 : making one collection for every two user contains (their messages)

option 2 : making one collection for all users contains (all users messages ) with using `.where(id)` later for return data to per 2 users depends id .

now in the first option, the collection will be smaller than second one but will not give me additional wide features in quires side

in the second option the collection will be very large but at the same time It will give me the ability to have additional features for quires like if i want make messages search ... etc.

Because literally, in second option if we imagine what does one collection means to all the users’ messages, it will be very big

My preference is towards the second option, but I am concerned that it is not a good option or maybe that it will cause the following

- large storage operations and a large cost
- slow response to fetching data if it grows in the future.
- Or something bad that I don't know about (My concerns are not limited to the previous two sentences)

Or is it just a matter of organization, and is there no difference between the two options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading from Firestore both the performance and the cost are solely based on the number of documents you actually read/return. Neither the read performance nor the cost of reading is based on the number of documents in the collection.

---

What ***is*** affected by this choice is the [performance and scalability of write operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#designing_for_scale).

- Say you have all messages in a single collection and have an index on the timestamp of each message there, then the Firestore servers will have to update that index for every message between any two users - which will lead to write hotspots when you have lots of users/messages.
- Conversely, if you put the messages for each conversation/user pair in their own collection, then you are much less likely to encounter a write hotspot - as the index is only on the messages between those users.
- But if you then decide to add a [collection group index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), you will again be back in the scenario of the first bullet - as that index will need to be written for each conversation.

Comment: thank you . i really appreciate this , but can you please tell me What are the bad symptoms of the your phrase :=> will lead to write hotspots when you have lots of users/messages. performance issue ?

Comment: From the first doc I linked on that: "At high enough write rates, the database will start to encounter contention, higher latency, or other errors."

Comment: Your answer has radically benefited my life , million thanks Frank !!

Comment: thank you : last question , "At high enough write rates" , does it mean high enough write rates for generally to whole collections or  high enough write rates in one specific collection that has lots? , This is not clear in the document